# TCF Debug: Unresolved source line information

Tags: eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a simple C program using TCF.

It basically works, but the problem is, that I only see the disassembly but without any debug informatione - so just the machine code.

This is how gcc (using MinGW) is called:

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.c" 
gcc -o debugme.exe main.o
```

Whereas ths is the TCF Trace:

```
360.192 Inp: E Breakpoints status "file:/C:/Users/falkstef/runtime-EclipseApplication/test/main.c:3703" {Instances:[{LocationContext:"P7092",Error:"Unresolved source line information"}]}
360.192 Inp: E Breakpoints status "file:/C:/Users/falkstef/runtime-EclipseApplication/test/main.c:3697" {Instances:[{LocationContext:"P7092",Error:"Unresolved source line information"}]}
360.192 Inp: E Breakpoints status "file:/C:/Users/falkstef/runtime-EclipseApplication/test/main.c:3701" {Instances:[{LocationContext:"P7092",Error:"Unresolved source line information"}]}
360.192 Inp: E Breakpoints status "file:/C:/Users/falkstef/runtime-EclipseApplication/debugme/main.c:3717" {Instances:[{LocationContext:"P7092",Error:"Unresolved source line information"}]}
...
360.468 Out: C 1778 Symbols findByAddr "P7092" 2003398832
360.468 Inp: R 1778 {Format:"Symbol not found",Time:1386328360468,Code:22} null
360.469 Out: C 1779 Symbols findByAddr "P7092" 2003398833
360.469 Inp: R 1779 {Format:"Symbol not found",Time:1386328360469,Code:22} null
360.469 Out: C 1780 Symbols findByAddr "P7092" 2003398834
360.469 Inp: R 1780 {Format:"Symbol not found",Time:1386328360469,Code:22} null
360.469 Out: C 1781 Symbols findByAddr "P7092" 2003398835
...
```

Can anyone help me here?

**Update 1**
Running services according to the Locator Hello Message:

```
["ZeroCopy","Diagnostics","Profiler","Disassembly","DPrintf",
"Terminals","PathMap","Streams","Expressions","SysMonitor",
"FileSystem","ProcessesV1","Processes","LineNumbers",
"Symbols","StackTrace","Registers","MemoryMap","Memory",
"Breakpoints","RunControl","ContextQuery","Locator"]
```

**Update 2**

```
// .. somewhere in linenumberswin32.c
    if (!SymGetLineFromName(get_context_handle(ctx), NULL, file, line, &offset, &img_line)) {

            DWORD win_err = GetLastError();
            if (win_err != ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
                err = set_win32_errno(win_err);
            }
        }
// ...
```

See [defenition of SymGetLineFromName64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// this returns false:
BOOL SymGetLineFromName(HANDLE hProcess, PCSTR ModuleName, PCSTR FileName, DWORD dwLineNumber, PLONG plDisplacement, PIMAGEHLP_LINE Line) {
    typedef BOOL (FAR WINAPI * ProcType)(HANDLE, PCSTR, PCSTR, DWORD, PLONG, PIMAGEHLP_LINE);
    static ProcType proc = NULL;
    if (proc == NULL) {
        proc = (ProcType)GetProc("SymGetLineFromName");
        if (proc == NULL) return 0;
    }
    return proc(hProcess, ModuleName, FileName, dwLineNumber, plDisplacement, Line);
}
```

**Update 3** Screenshot ([direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsmRi.png))

[image]

Comment: could you list the TCF services running in your TCF Agent? A somewhat hackish way to do that is connecting using telnet on the TCF port ; you then get the service enumeration from the service Locator

Comment: This is the Locator Hello message: `E Locator Hello ["ZeroCopy","Diagnostics","Profiler","Disassembly","DPrintf","Terminals","PathMap","Streams","Expressions","SysMonitor","FileSystem","ProcessesV1","Processes","LineNumbers","Symbols","StackTrace","Registers","MemoryMap","Memory","Breakpoints","RunControl","ContextQuery","Locator"]`.

Comment: Ok looks like you have all the required services. Normally the service LineNumbers is also used to convert addresses to lines.

Comment: Next questions: 1. did you add a symbol file? You can check if the current debug context has symbol files mapped in the Modules view. 2. If it is the case you can use the expressions view to evaluate symbols such as functions name and global variables. Does it work?

Comment: Well, no.. I am not able to add a symbol file. There is no `Debug Context` listed. When I debug the agent, I can see that `SymGetLineFromName`, called from `dbghelp.dll` returns `false`. (See **Update 2** in my question).

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I'm following, you should have at least one debug context in the debug view to display the disassembly. Could you post a screenshot of the Debug perspective?

Comment: I did add a screenshot. I didn't notice, that those contexts are loaded when I `debug` the program but anyway .. there are no information displayed.

Comment: Ok. Did you try resolving main in the Expressions view? I see that you are running an .exe program built with MinGW on Windows and I don't know if this is supported (TCF supports ELF+DWARF or PE+dbghelp.)

Comment: The Expression view does not display anything. MinGW `objdump` tells me that the `main.o` file is `pe-i386`, I think this should be okay? I updated the `dbghelp.dll` as recommended by the TCF specs.

Comment: @ChristopheAugier I have added the symbol files and I'm able to see the symbol files mapped in the modules view, the expression view is also working with the function but I'm not able to add a breakpoint, Note: I'm using a ELF+Dwarf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan, you won't be able to debug this file using the current implementation of TCF because the file you generated using MinGW is in the PE file format but the debug information are in DWARF. As far as I know this is not supported by TCF right now, only by GDB. See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875197/mingw-gcc-compilation-and-gdb-debugging).

I suggest you build a new .exe file using Visual Studio which will generate a PE file with MS debug format or that you switch to Linux (ELF + DWARF)

Comment: Thank you Christophe! That would make sense and I will check this out. I will mark your answer as valid as soon as I am back to work to verify this. But now I am sure you're right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope so. I think that I will have to implement the whole support for debugging with the debug information provided by SDCC (which will be the compiler that is going to be used). I think I will have to make a lot of changes/additions to the current TCF agent. :)